# correct way of modifying a passed argument in the same way for many objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some rails services which (depending on the service) accept a specific type of object, an Array of that object, or an ActiveRecord::Relation of that object.

So:

FooService accepts Foo objects, BarService accepts Bar objects, etc.

But..all the service objects want to massage what is passed in into an array of their given objects.

within the scope of the called service method I could do this pretty easily.
I was trying to DRY things up and make a method to do this for all services, because each of them had the same chunk of code. Unfortunately,  I run into issues with Ruby.

For example:

```
def change_obj(element)
  element = [element]
end



blah = "hello"

change_obj(blah)

puts blah.class.to_s #I want it to be an array with the  string in it now.
```

I understand why it doesn't work. But, I don't have a clear idea of what the correct way to do this is.

Ideally I want something like:

```
class BarService < Service

 def initialize(foo)

   @foo = foo

 end


 def do_something(bars)

  massage_to_array(bars) #method inherited from Service. if bars is an ActiveRecordRelation, convert it to array..if bars is a singular object, flip it to an array with that object as the sole element.
  process_array_of_bars(bars)

 end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bars = massage_to_array(bars)
process_array_of_bars(bars)
```

Comment: also, just FYI - you can use Array(bars) which will work correctly even if it's already an array and in your original method there's no reason to assign the array back to elements

Answer (score 1):

as long as you are modifying passed object - ruby will keep the reference and update contents of that object and not create new object. For example if you pass an array as argument and then add element to an array inside the method - ruby will add element to the object that was passed in, but if you re-assign value to the object, then ruby will remove the reference to passed object and create new object in the local scope and add reference to it to the variable name.

That being said, you can still achieve similar result by creating class that will acts as a proxy. Remember ruby will maintain reference to original object as long as you dont re-assign the variable name to new variable. For example

```
class ArgProxy
  attr_accessor :arg_object

  def initialize(arg=nil)
    self.arg_object = arg
  end
end

def some_method(arg_proxy)
  arg_proxy.arg_object = [arg_proxy.arg_object]
end

arg_proxy = ArgProxy.new("qwerty")
some_method(arg_proxy)

arg_proxy.arg_object #=> ["qwerty"]
```

Comment: exactly. Because the variable is changing classes and not just gutting the existing object, the variable gets pointed to a new object. The proxy object will work but I was really hoping not to have to do that. I likely have to use this option and reorganize the services to suit.